# Add hashmap having possible serialized JSON values to a JSON string as a node

Tags: java, json, hashmap

What is the cheapest way to take the `jsonstring` and `hashmap` below and produce the `result` in JAVA?

pseudocode data example:

```
String jsonstring = {
  "people": {
    "name": "name1", 
  },
  "addresses": {
    "address1": {
      "number": "1234",
      "city": "europa"
    }
  }
}

HashMap hashmap = {
  ["string.a.1"] = "stringa1", 
  ["string.a.2"] = "stringa2", 
  ["object.a.1"] = "{/"item1/":/"value1/"}" // serialized JSON object
}

String result = {
  "people": {
    "name": "name1", 
  },
  "addresses": {
    "address1": {
      "number": "1234",
      "city": "europa"
    }
  },
  "buffer": {
    "string.a.1": "stringa1", 
    "string.a.2": "stringa2", 
    "object.a.1": {
      "item1": "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look at any java JSON library like Jackson or you could manipulate this with simple string as well.

Comment: Thanks @Shivang I have looked at many, and I know how I would do this inexpensively in JavaScript.  I'm asking JAVA experts how they would solve this in the most inexpensive way.  I should mention these are quite large objects and I'm leaning toward string manipulation of some kind.